# Is there a way to implement inheritance priority mutex in win32?

Tags: c, winapi, random, mutex, priority-inversion

I've read the documentation about [priority inversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/priority-inversion) in win32. It seems that the operating system's scheduler handles this case by boosting a waiting thread's priority randomly.

Does that mean that there is no deterministic way to know if a mutex will have priority inheritance during a given critical section? Is there a way to implement it?

I've checked some ways to [set thread priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority) but it should be a property of the mutex, not of the thread that holds it.

Thanks for answering

Comment: Can I take it this way? You want to set the mutex property. Is this equivalent to a semaphore or event？

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Priority is a property of a thread. I'm at a loss what *"it should be a property of the mutex"* even means. What should the *"priority of a mutex"* be in case two or more threads with different priorities are waiting on it?